# MySql CLI - alias/name for queries

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, alias

Sometimes I write complex queries that span across ten+ lines. Then I need those queries inside other complex queries. Is it possible to give query a name and simply let that name be replaced at runtime by actual query?

For example:

```
SET var_a = 'select f1, sum(f2) where .... (select .. from (select .. from))';
SET var_b = 'select g1, sum(g2) where .... (select .. from (select .. from))';

select z1, z2 from var_a union var_b;
```

Can mysql CLI do some simple string replacement like bash can? That way I don't need to bother with creating view just to clean them up on exit.

Comment: You could construct the SQL using such variables in whatever higher-level language is accessing MySQL.

Comment: I know that. But maybe the same is possible with mysql standard tools? Just wanted to know if it is.

Comment: And no. I can't use temporary tables, because they store values. Query can display different values at different times and I would like to see if they have updated.

Answer (score 1):

The closes solution I found is this:

```
SET @var_a = 'select f1, sum(f2) where .... (select .. from (select .. from))';
SET @var_b = 'select g1, sum(g2) where .... (select .. from (select .. from))';

SET @s = CONCAT('select ... from (', @var_a, ' union all ', @var_b, ')a');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt;
```

A little bit bulky, but it works.

Comment: Isn't that the solution I set out in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042541/mysql-cli-alias-name-for-queries/21042948#comment31637090_21042948)?

Answer (score 0):

You could define [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-view.html)s from your `SELECT` statements:

```
CREATE VIEW var_a AS
  SELECT f1, SUM(f2) WHERE .... (SELECT .. FROM (SELECT .. FROM));

CREATE VIEW var_b AS
  SELECT g1, SUM(g2) WHERE .... (SELECT .. FROM (SELECT .. FROM));
```

And then use them as "tables" in subsequent queries:

```
SELECT f1 FROM var_a UNION SELECT g1 FROM var_b
```

Comment: I know you can. But views is not a replacement for _any_ query that can be part of other query. Or even parts of it, like: SET var_where = 'WHERE .... some very complex condition selection...'

Comment: @EvgenijM86: Such SQL construction should be performed in the higher language from which you access MySQL.

Comment: @EvgenijM86: You could store SQL parts as strings in [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html), from which you then [`PREPARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/prepare.html) and [`EXECUTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/execute.html) a statement.